# How to access application level variables in Puppet

Tags: puppet

I know this question can be open to interpretation so I will ask for specifics.

I am leveraging Puppet to keep some application level variables and settings in check. The problem I am having is a lot of these variables are not set in facts like things like operatingsystem, hostname, ipaddress, etc. I am then having trouble trying to figure out how to leverage puppet to create variables to act on.

For example, I have some servers that are running different versions of an application and so I need to be able to figure out what version is running on the server. **How can I do this?**

My first thoughts are that since these facts are not provided in the standard facts list that I should create facts of my own that I can leverage and so I am doing something like the following:

```
module_name
|
|---manifests
|---files
|---examples
|---facts.d
   |---script.sh
```

In my script.sh I am executing linux commands to get variables from the application. and then echoing them out in the format

```
key=value
```

So where the application version is stored I would find that location and then echo out the version. Then at runtime I can use a variable like $app_ver to make specific configuration changes. Such as

```
app_ver=1.0.8
java_ver=1.7
```

1. Is this the correct way of defining external facts?
2. Are there standard ways of getting Application-Level details?
3. When puppet applies on a given app server, will the script.sh run, provide facts and then make those variables available to the puppet master to determine config changes?
4. Will the computation in the script.sh file have to run on every server that matches this class?

Comment: Yes, No, Yes: pluginsync occurs before catalog comp[ilation, Yes: your servers may have different versions of the app installed.

Comment: So basically you want to get the version of a particular application installed on the server where you apply puppet module?

Comment: Yes, and other things. For example different versions of the application run different versions of java. Based on the java versions I would like to ensure particular settings based on that version.

Comment: there is a function in puppet called `generate`.
In your puppet manifest you can do something like ->
`$app_ver = generate("bash -c 'shell command to get the version'")`

Comment: Be careful, @AtmeshMishra.  Puppet functions run *during catalog building*, on the machine where the catalog is built.  You cannot, therefore, use `generate()` as you describe in conjunction with a master / agent Puppet setup because in such an environment, catalogs are built on the master, not on the target machines.

Comment: @jacksonecac, there are some resources and resource properties that it makes sense to query as facts, but most are more appropriate to *manage* into a chosen state.  How exactly that breaks down is site-specific, but whenever you conceive a need to query some piece of target machine state, you should always ask yourself whether it is something that you can instead manage.

Comment: @JohnBollinger: How do we get output of bash command in a variable if we have a master-slave setup?

Comment: @AtmeshMishra, that's what facts are for.  Specifically, although you *could* do it with a Ruby-based custom fact, the simpler external fact approach is very well suited to this particular job.